# How do I use a for loop and output to a different directory

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, ms-dos, xpdf

```
 usage: pdftotext [options] <PDF-file> [<text-file>]
```

I'm using pdftotext (xpft, usage above) to covert all pdfs in a directory (and subdirectories) to textfiles.  It doesn't matter if structure is preserved or not I just want to write the files to a different directory.

I have cmd cd already pointing at the directory ("C:\input" say ).

So if the path of a given input file is

```
 C:\input\filename.pdf
```

And I want to output to

```
 C:\output\filename.txt
```

My command:

```
 for /r %i in (*.pdf) do pdftotext "%i" -raw "C:\output\%i"
```

Nearly works, but it attempts to output to

```
 C:\input\C:\output\filename
```

which obviously causes an error.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I use a for loop and output to a different directory

Use the following command:

```
for /r %i in (*.pdf) do pdftotext -raw "%i" "C:\output\%~ni.txt"
```

- `%~ni` Expands `%i` to a file name only (i.e. removes drive letter, path and `.pdf` extension)
- `%~ni.txt` also appends a new extension, `.txt`

---

#### Extended syntax

> When an argument is used to supply a filename then the following
> extended syntax can be applied:
>
> we are using the variable %1 (but this works for any parameter)
>
> - %~f1 Expand %1 to a Fully qualified path name - C:\utils\MyFile.txt
> - %~d1 Expand %1 to a Drive letter only - C:
> - %~p1 Expand %1 to a Path only e.g. \utils\ this includes a trailing \ which will be interpreted as an escape character by some
>   commands.
> - %~n1 Expand %1 to a file Name without file extension C:\utils\MyFile or if only a path is present (with no trailing
>   backslash) - the last folder in that path.
> - %~x1 Expand %1 to a file eXtension only - .txt
> - %~s1 Change the meaning of f, n, s and x to reference the Short 8.3 name (if it exists.)
> - %~1   Expand %1 removing any surrounding quotes (")
> - %~a1 Display the file attributes of %1
> - %~t1 Display the date/time of %1
> - %~z1 Display the file size of %1
> - %~$PATH:1 Search the PATH environment variable and expand %1 to the fully qualified name of the first match found.
>
> The modifiers above can be combined:
>
> - %~dp1 Expand %1 to a drive letter and path only
> - %~sp1 Expand %1 to a path shortened to 8.3 characters
> - %~nx2 Expand %2 to a file name and extension only

Source [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/n/syntax-args.html)

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.

Comment: This answer is a goddamned perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, except it doesn't actually work.  It seems that in fact it is using the last %i as the input file not the output and so the reason 

`for /r %i in (*.pdf) do pdftotext "%i"`

works is because pdftotext automatically creates a text file in the same directory if no output directory is specified

So what I actually want is 

`for /r %i in (*.pdf) do pdftotext -raw "%i" "C:\output\%~ni.txt"`

Comment: I'll edit both question and answer appropriately